# Overriding ASP.NET Core Windows Authentication Identity

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, active-directory, blazor, windows-identity

I was looking to use Windows Authentication for a Blazor Server app, but hit a small issue with the default Identity Name.
i.e. when you used

```
<AuthorizeView>
   Hi @context.User.Identity.Name
</AuthorizeView>
```

I got back 'Hi DOMAIN\A123456', which might be the AD object name, but its not what users would say their name was.  I also noticed during debugging that the Identity had pulled back all of my AD groups, but not things like Given Name.

How can I override/amend/alter the processing to 'fix' this, ideally put a proper name in the `Name` claim and move the id into the `NameIdentifier` claim.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with using `IClaimsTransformation`, but not sure if its the right approach at all, esp given that with just the out-of-the-box Blazor project this thing is called 7 times! If I added any db type logic to get the roles or name then this is going tank performance...

```
public class RoleClaimsTransformer : IClaimsTransformation
{
    private readonly ILogger<RoleClaimsTransformer> _logger;

    public RoleClaimsTransformer(ILogger<RoleClaimsTransformer> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
    {
        _logger.LogDebug($"Role Transform for {principal.Identity.Name} Auth: {principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated}");

        //get the original name claim
        var ci = (ClaimsIdentity)principal.Identity;
        Claim nameClaim = principal.FindFirst(ci.NameClaimType);

        //create a new principal
        ClaimsPrincipal newCP = new ClaimsPrincipal();
        //and a new identity, using the original authtype (just in case it matters down the line)
        var newId = new GenericIdentity("Joe Bloggs", principal.Identity.AuthenticationType);
        //add the original name as a NameId
        newId.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, nameClaim.Value));
        //add roles etc
        newId.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "admin"));

        newCP.AddIdentity(newId);

        return Task.FromResult(newCP);
    }
}
```

Hopefully its reasonably clear what I've done, but basically ignore the principal from the built in Windows Auth and create your own.  Also note that the `GenericIdentity` does want a `ClaimTypes.Role` for roles (for use in the `AuthorizeView` components), and not whatever type the `WindowsIdentity` needed.

I've subsequently realised that WindowsAuthentication isn't not going to work for my app, and I'll go back to custom auth that just uses AD to check their passwords via a standard pair of login boxes.